# Is there a way to turn sys.fn_varbintohexstr result back to varbinary?

Tags: sql-server, function, hex, varbinary

Is there a `function` in `SQL Server` to do that?
to reverse `sys.fn_varbintohexstr`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the hexadecimal character string in a dynamic SQL statement, so that it will be parsed as a varbinary. Here's one example of how to do that.

```
-- Our original and fn_varbintohexstr values:
DECLARE @original varbinary(max) = 0xd0cf11;
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SET @converted = ' + sys.fn_varbintohexstr(@original) + ';';

-- Do the conversion
DECLARE @converted varbinary(max);
EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
   N'@converted varbinary(max) OUTPUT',
   @converted = @converted OUTPUT;

-- Proof it worked
PRINT @original;
PRINT @converted;
PRINT CASE WHEN @original = @converted THEN 'Same' ELSE 'Different' END;
```

This prints `Same`.

If you try user1617237's version, you'll see why it is not a correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

select convert(varbinary（max),@hex,2) from foobar

Comment: This doesn't work. You do get `varbinary` out of it, but it's the varbinary of the string representation of the original varbinary. It's not the original varbinary.