# How to convert hex string to binary in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How can i convert a hex string in SQL Server to binary?

Better yet, how can i convert a hex string in SQL Server to an integer?

The problem is that every existing answer on Stackoverflow assumes SQL Server 2008.

## Failed attempts

- **[Convert hex string to binary SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39674205/convert-hex-string-to-binary-sql-server)**

  ```
  SELECT CONVERT(binary(16),'0x01',1)
  0x30783031000000000000000000000000
  ```
- **[SQL Server hex string to varbinary conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145904/sql-server-hex-string-to-varbinary-conversion)**

  ```
  select CONVERT(varbinary(max), '0x01', 1);
  0x30783031

  select CONVERT(varbinary(max), '01', 2);
  0x3031
  ```
- **[Convert integer to hex and hex to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703019/convert-integer-to-hex-and-hex-to-integer)**

  ```
  -- If the '0x' marker is present:
  SELECT CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARBINARY, '0x000001', 1))
  808464433

  -- If the '0x' marker is NOT present:
  SELECT CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARBINARY, '000001', 2))
  808464433
  ```

### Edit

...yes 2005 has varbinary. Even 2000 has `varbinary`:

```
SELECT name, xtype FROM systypes WHERE name LIKE '%binary%'; 
SELECT @@version;

name       xtype
---------  -----
varbinary  165
binary     173

(No column name)
---------------------------------
Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.2039 (Intel X86) 
May  3 2005 23:18:38 
Copyright (c) 1988-2003 Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition on Windows NT 5.0 (Build 2195: Service Pack 4)
```

[Even SQL Server 6.5 has varbinary.](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/1442371/SQL-Server-65-Datatypes.htm) *([archive](http://archive.is/C9iPK))*Interesting, and typical SO fashion, to try to circumvent the question rather than answer it.

Comment: Did SQL even have a varbinary data type in 2005?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for values that can be represented as a bigint

```
DECLARE @Hex VARCHAR(10)='0x3078'
DECLARE @DecValue BIGINT=0
DECLARE @Power TINYINT = 0

SET @Hex=REVERSE(REPLACE(@Hex,'0x',''))
WHILE LEN(@Hex)>0
BEGIN
    SET @DecValue=@DecValue+(POWER(16,@Power)*CONVERT(TINYINT,LEFT(@Hex,1)))
    SET @Power=@Power+1
    SET @Hex=RIGHT(@Hex,LEN(@Hex)-1)
END

SELECT @DecValue AS [Decimal value]
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2005 had a function `master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr()` (apparently in SQL Server 2000 [it was called](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/issues/273) `dbo.fn_varbintohexstr`) to convert binary to string.

Searching for this function name brings up answers for converting hex strings to binary, such as [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40009294/21336), or [Social MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a44e39b4-6dea-4130-b201-b5d4fc1d8015/converting-a-hex-string-to-a-varbinary-or-vice-versa?forum=transactsql) (useful code, but lots of dead links), or [this MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqltips/2008/07/02/converting-from-hex-string-to-varbinary-and-vice-versa/) using XQuery to parse a hex string.